# WPF MVVM Creating Dynamic controls

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, dynamic, controls

WPF MVVM Creating Dynamic controls - I have a grid on which I have a job's (you can say something like a sql server job) details.

Now for every job there could be 'n' number of job variables. When I fetch the record for a job it gets this collection of Job variables which are Name-value pair, where value could be a collection or a datetime value or even an int or a string.

Now what I am trying to achieve here is : 
-- If the run variable is a datetime then I need a datepicker 
-- If it is a int/String I need a text box 
-- If it is a collection then a combo box .
-- it it is a bit field then a check box

I am not sure how to achieve it since these values can differ for every single job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am assuming that you will put some kind of objects representing these name/value pairs into an `ItemsControl` by setting its `ItemsSource` property.

There are a couple of solutions you can use.

### Using a `DataTemplate` with triggers:

This approach involves exposing the "type" of each of your objects through the `YourPropertyType` property as a string. You will set the `ItemTemplate` of your `ItemsControl` to a template which hosts  a `ContentControl`. The `ContentControl` itself will have its `ContentTemplate` selected dynamically with triggers.

All of this can be done declaratively in XAML.

I am assuming you have further `DataTemplates` named `DefaultTemplate` (this can be empty), `IntegerTemplate`, `StringTemplate`, etc to sketch out the visual tree for each case.

This would then be the `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ContentControl
        x:Name="MyContentControl"
        Content="{Binding}"
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}"/>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourPropertyType}" Value="Integer">
            <Setter TargetName="MyContentControl" Property="ContentTemplate"
                    Value="{StaticResource IntegerTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding YourPropertyType}" Value="String">
            <Setter TargetName="MyContentControl" Property="ContentTemplate"
                    Value="{StaticResource StringTemplate}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <!-- and so on -->
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

### Using a `DataTemplateSelector`:

This approach requires code-behind, but it does not force you to expose the "type" of each name/value pair as a string and it allows you to choose which template to use with much more complex logic.

It involves creating a class to be the template selector:

```
class YourObjectDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        var yourObject = (YourObjectType) item;

        // Get hold of a DataTemplate based on any attribute of item
        var templateToUse = this.DefaultTemplate;

        return templateToUse;
    }
}
```

Then, you need to instantiate a template selector somewhere (let's say inside your `UserControl`)

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <localNamespace:YourObjectDataTemplateSelector
      x:Key="TemplateSelector"
      DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}"
    />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Notice that I exposed a `DefaultTemplate` property from `YourObjectDataTemplateSelector` and set that to a template from XAML. In practice, you would define more properties of type `DataTemplate` on `YourObjectDataTemplateSelector`, and "configure" the template selector when adding it into the resource dictionary of your control. This allows you to directly set the templates for each case using the `StaticResource` markup extension from XAML.

Finally, wire the template selector to your `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl 
  ItemsSource="..."
  ItemTemplateSelector={StaticResource TemplateSelector}"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking at using some form of [Data Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) and the [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) to achieve what you are after.