# Change control in a DataGridRow programmatically

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid contains a list of Products with an image button in the last column to add the Product item into the Orders_Products collection. That works.

Now I'd like to change the "add" image button with a "delete" image button if the Product item is already in the Orders_Products collection.

I tried to use the LoadingRow event but it seems there's no way to access the Image object because is not ready yet in the LoadingRow event...

I tried the Load event of the Image object, but it's not fired if the row is not visible in the form (when I must scroll the datagrid to see that row). It fires when I sort a column and the row is directly visible in the form. I'm going crazy... :(

I think I'm not doing something unusual but I'm new to WPF and probably I miss something.

Can someone give me an hint?
Thanks in advance,
Joe

P.S.: I'm using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of doing this is by binding the `DataGrid` to the collection of objects you want to display (you are probably doing this already).

Then, manually define a `DataGridTemplateColumn` and set its `CellTemplate` to an appropriate `DataTemplate` (this would usually be defined as a resource in your `DataGrid` or somewhere higher in the logical tree of elements).

You can see an example of how the above is done [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn.celltemplate%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Inside the `DataTemplate`, use the technique described in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5267905/50079) to vary what is displayed in the template by matching the value of an appropriate property in the databound `Product`.

All of this can be done entirely in XAML, as is the preferred way of doing things in WPF.

### Update (working example)

The `Product`:

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Exists { get; set; }
}
```

`MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.Products = new List<Product>
            {
                new Product { Name = "Existing product", Exists = true },
                new Product { Name = "This one does not exist", Exists = false },
            };

        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

`MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="SandboxWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonColumnTemplate" >
                <ContentControl x:Name="MyContentControl" Content="{Binding}" />
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Exists}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="MyContentControl" Property="ContentTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Your Remove product button goes here" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Exists}" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="MyContentControl" Property="ContentTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Your Add product button goes here" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Product Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Add/Remove" CellTemplate="{StaticResource ButtonColumnTemplate}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```