# Dynamically Creating Controls Following MVVM pattern

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, mvvm-light, dataform

I'd like to dynamically generate some controls in my silverlight application.
To be more clear, here's a simplified definition of my class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    [Display(Name="First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public List<CustomProperty> CustomProperties { get; set; }
}
```

Each "CustomProperty" will finally be a TextBox, CheckBox or ComboBox:

```
public class CustomProperty
{
    public CustomDataType DataType { get; set; } //enum:integer, string, datetime, etc
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string Mappings { get; set; } // Simulating enums' behavior.
}
```

- What is the best way to implement this using MVVM pattern? If I parse CustomProperties in ViewModel, and find out which controls should be created, How can I create new controls in my view based on MVVM pattern.
- Is there any silverlight control that can help me make the UI faster?
- Can I define data annotations programmatically? for example after parsing the custom property, can I add some data annotations (Display, Validation) to the property and bind it to a DataForm, PropertyGrid or a useful control for this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: For the first question, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267905/wpf-mvvm-creating-dynamic-controls/5267964#5267964). It's WPF instead of Silverlight, but there's a good chance you will be able to apply it verbatim.

Comment: @Jon: thanks for the link. I'll try to implement it tomorrow. Is it possible to update the data (something like two-way binding) with data templates too?

Comment: Sure it is, it's just a more flexible way of specifying the visual tree for an object. You can do the same things you could if you had it hardcoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In these cases you usualy use one of the controls inheriting from `ItemsControl` (e.g. `ListBox`) or the `ItemsControl` directly. The controls inheriting from `ItemsControl` allow you to define a template for each item in a collection, e.g. using your sample (assuming you got access to your `TestClass` through a view model):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TestClass.CustomProperties }">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!--DataContext is stet to item in the ItemsSource (of type CustomProperty)-->
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This snippet creates a `ListBox` that contains a label and a text box for each `CustonProperty` in your `CustomProperties` collection.