# PropertyGrid for Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, propertygrid

Following [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7378218/337294), Is there a (preferably free) PropertyGrid for silverlight out there which supports editing ICollections?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a newest version of the same control and according to the documentation it is supporting `Collections`. You could find it in [Silverlight 5 Property Grid](http://slg50.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

http://slg40.codeplex.com/

Is something like this what you are looking for?

Comment: I've checked it out before. Unforunately, it doesn't support ICollections.