# DatagridTemplateColumn with triggers failed to bind

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a datagrid that contain of the 2 columns and I would like to show some of cells in column#2 to be:

1. ComboBox
2. TextBox

based on property

code :

**Solution #1 :**

```
 <Window.Resources> 
<DataTemplate x:Key="DropDownTemplate">
     <StackPanel>

      <ComboBox  SelectedValuePath="Id" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  ItemsSource="{Binding MarketConfigurationLOVs, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

       </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
      <StackPanel>
           <TextBox Text="{Binding ConfigurationValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />


       </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
 </Window.Resources>
```

Here the datagrid tags :

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path= MarketConfigurationValues,Mode=TwoWay}" HeadersVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
             <DataGridTextColumn Width="120" Binding="{Binding  Path= ConfigurationName}" />


             <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                              <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" >
                                     <ContentControl.Style>
                                          <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                                               <Style.Triggers>

                                                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasLOV}" Value="true">
                                                         <Setter  Property="ContentTemplate"  Value="{StaticResource DropDownTemplate}" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasLOV}" Value="false">
                                                         <Setter  Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}" />
                                                            </DataTrigger>
                                                            <!-- and so on -->
                                                        </Style.Triggers>
                                                    </Style>
                                                </ContentControl.Style>
                                            </ContentControl>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

   </DataGrid.Columns>
```

this failed to show  actual value as it show the name of property and always show cell in dropdown and when I swapped the TextBoxContentTemplate with ComboBoxContentTemplate it show all cells as textBox so it seem it ignore the trigger however when I debug I found the HasLOV some items contain true and some contain false

**Solution #2 :** **(also failed)** Reference : Jon solution from the following post [WPF MVVM Creating Dynamic controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267905/wpf-mvvm-creating-dynamic-controls)

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <ContentControl x:Name="MyContentControl" Content="{Binding}" />

         <DataTemplate.Triggers>
              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasLOV}" Value="false">
                    <Setter  TargetName="MyContentControl" Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}" />
              </DataTrigger>

              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasLOV}" Value="true">
                    <Setter  TargetName="MyContentControl"  Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DropDownTemplate}" />
              </DataTrigger>

         </DataTemplate.Triggers>

      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**ViewModel** is big class but I pulled here the main parts related to my problem . In constructor I created list of  MarketConfigurationValue and I filled values inside MarketConfigurationLOVs in case if I set HasLov=true  and I filled value in configurationValue in case if I set HasLov=false and I run the application and in debug mode I found the main object List contain what I said correctly but it failed to show comboBox in  case HasLov=true and textBox in case HasLov=false :

```
public class MarketConfigurationValue
    {
        public string ConfigurationName { get; set; }
        public string ConfigurationValue { get; set; }
        public int ConfigurationValueId { get; set; }
        public List<Market_Config_Lov> MarketConfigurationLOVs {get;set;}
        public bool HasLov { get; set; }

    }

public class Market_Config_Lov 
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual int Sequence { get; set; }
    }
```

Can you please help ?

Comment: Try tp replace Content={Binding} through DataContext={Binding} in your ContentControl.

Comment: Try putting the triggers under DataTemplate.Triggers. Maybe this can help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18303/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-4-Data-templates-and-tri

Comment: @Florian GI : when I replace Content={Binding} with DataContext={Binding} to be :   <ContentControl  DataContext="{Binding}" > the text box is always empty and no drop down

Comment: I think it would be helpful to see your ViewModel.

Comment: @Florian GI : I updated the post to contain ViewModel you can check it now

Comment: @Per : I updated post section solution#2 with DataTemplate trigger solution but it also failed

Comment: Try to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface in your MarketConfigurationValue Class. Then add a method called OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) where the PropertyChanged Event is fired. Call this method in the setter of HasLOV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface. With this the binding updates itself when the setter of HasLOV is called.

```
public class MarketConfigurationValue:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _hasLOV;
    public bool HasLOV 
    { 
        get {return _hasLOV;} 
        set {_hasLOV = value; OnPropertyChanged("HasLOV");}
    }  
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        VerifyPropertyName(propertyName);

        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            var e = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

====>The property  name is typo as the property in class called : HasLov and in XAML called HasLOV .

Comment: I separate this piece in a standalone project and I would like you to check it . Can I attach it here or send it to you directly to you ?

Comment: You can send it to my email adress ;)

Comment: I can not find your email . please send note to my email thabet084@hotmail.com and I will reply with attachemnt

Comment: yes I can not you seem hide it or I do not know form where I got the email contact of user

Comment: fixed my issue as the issue was typo the property name is HasLov  and I used a typo property in xaml HasLOV . Thanks Florian for your support .